# Why are all my turtles dying when I ask only one of them to?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make a program where if a turtle detects a turtle ahead of it, it dies. Simple, but for some reason whenever one instance of this occurs, all of my turtles die, and I can't figure out how to correct this.

Here is my code:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask patches
  [ set pcolor white
  ]
end

to spawn
  crt 1
  [ set color random 140
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end

to wiggle
  lt 100
  rt 100
  ifelse not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
  [ fd 1
    set pcolor color
  ]
  [ die
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [ wiggle
  ]
end
```

It seems that `ifelse not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1` at one point always starts to evaluate as false, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following example might shed a bit of light on what's happening to you:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1 [
    set xcor -0.5
    set ycor -0.5
    set heading 45
    show (word "patch-here:    " patch-here)
    show (word "patch-ahead 1: " patch-ahead 1)
    show (word "patch-ahead 1: " patch-ahead 1)
    show (word 
      "not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1:       "
      not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    )
    show (word 
      "not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1: "
      not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    )
  ]
end
```

It's creating one turtle, placing it on the bottom left corner of the central patch and making it face north east, before checking for a few things. If you run the code, you'll get:

```
observer> setup
(turtle 0): "patch-here:    (patch 0 0)"
(turtle 0): "patch-ahead 1: (patch 0 0)"
(turtle 0): "patch-ahead 1: (patch 0 0)"
(turtle 0): "not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1:       false"
(turtle 0): "not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1: true"
```

The key point is that the diagonal of a patch is longer than one (remember Pythagoras' theorem). This means that `patch-ahead 1` can still be the same patch that the turtle is on! In this case, `not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1` will be false. Since your turtles are moving randomly across the world, this is bound to happen eventually.

Luckily for you, there is a simple solution. Just use [`other`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other):

```
not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1
```